# Google Edge Cache : is it compatible with HTTPS?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, https, cache-control

After some configuration :

- setting response header Cache-control,
- deploying app with a custom domain name,

I managed to leverage the server-side **Edge Cache** of Google Front-End for some HTTP traffic on a sample app.
The cache hits appear in the Logs console as 204, while non-cached responses are 200.

My question is : can I expect the same behavior for a company website which enforces HTTPS ?

I guess it depends how the Google datacenter distibuted architecture works, and where the SSL certificates are stored, but my networking/security skills are limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm to you that the edge caching works for server side requests served over https as well, even though I have no insights on how it works inside the GFE.

I just ran a quick query in the logs of one of our app with a filter set to status:204 and to only see the hits doing 204 on a specific servlet (such as we do not see all the static content):
[image: screenshot of logs]

I do not think there is a way to see that the serving was https or add a query filter on the logs, but I manually verified that some of these are for served over https.

As you mentioned, cache control headers are required to get this working. Here are the cache control headers we set:

  Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600

  Pragma: Public

Comment: Thanks Jerome, this is good news for me. Could you specify if those hits were requested with a URL in the form `https://foobar.appspot.com/avatar/serve` , or `https://www.foobar.com/avatar/serve` ?